# Does the generator of the ideals of a finite chain ring divide the cardinality of the ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Sorry for another similar question; there's just so little information available online about finite chain rings. Let $R$ be a finite chain ring, meaning that there is an element $p \in R$ such that the (left) ideals form a chain under inclusion: $$\{0\} = Rp^{m+1} < Rp^m < ... < Rp < R,$$ where $m+1$ is the *length* of $R$. Let $F = R/Rp$ be the residue field. Would it be true, or would there be a way to prove, that $$\exists r\in R \text{ such that } rp = |F|^m = |R|?$$

Comment: What is a finite chain ring? (Are your rings commutative?)

Comment: The definition is the fact that there is an element such that its ideals form a chain under inclusion. Yes, they are commutative, local, and principal.

Comment: $rp$ is an element of the ring $R$, while $|R|$ is an integer: how can they be equal?

Comment: I guess only if they're both equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's true is because a finite chain ring is a type of local ring, which always has a characteristic of a prime power, and $F$ is always a power of that same prime. So adding $|R|$ $1$'s together will give you $0$, which is an element of $Rp$.